# How to match single digits and digits separated by a hyphen with string.match?

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to match for two types of strings. I wish to capture both of them, but I can only capture one so far.

```
function roll(input)
  min, high = string.match(input, '(%d+)-(%d+)');

  return min, high;
end
```

The input strings are: `10-100` and `10`

My first string returns as expected but my second (the single digit) returns `nil`/match not found.

I wish to check if the second part of the pattern is included or not, as it should always print out my `min` variable.

Comment: `return input:match'%d+', input:match'-(%d+)'`

Comment: You need to escape `-` with `%-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is to do it separately:

```
function roll(input)
  local min,high = string.match(input, '(%d+)-(%d+)')
  if min == nil then 
    min = string.match(input, '(%d+)')
  end
  return min, high
end

print(roll '10')
print(roll '10-100')
```

Comment: @Saucy Great! Since you have enough rep, please consider either upvoting answers you accept, or commenting what's missing to get an upvote. Welcome to SO!